# Controling The Location Of The "Confirm Navigation" Window with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

Often a user will misuse a Rich Internet Application, and attempt to use the browser's Back Button.  Such mistakes can be disruptive to changed but unsaved information, as in a Flash or Flex application.

It is a simple matter to alert the user for confirmation before leaving the page (see below).  However, I have a client who strongly desires the resulting "Confirm Navigation" window to appear on the SIDE of the screen, as opposed to the center, which by default, it currently does in all major browsers.

The window in question says different things depending on your browser, but how could I go about influencing the *position* at which it pops up?

Just so you are certain as to which window I'm referring:

If you use I.E. the window text will say: "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?"
If you use Google Chrome, the window title will say "Confirm Navigation".

To wit: Something similar to the following Javascript:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <script language="javascript"> 
 function SaveYourWork() {
   return('Please Save Your Work Before Leaving The Page.\n\nAre You Sure?');
 }
    window.onbeforeunload=SaveYourWork;
  </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
  <h2>Some R.I.A.</h2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

How can I make the confirmation window pop up in a location other than the very center of the browser window, such as the far left instead?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but my instinct is the answer is "you can't do that."  I could see a lot of ways to exploit such a function for malicious purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I make the confirmation window pop up in a location other than the very center of the browser window, such as the far left instead?

You won't be able to influence this. It is entirely under the control of the browser, like the native `confirm` and `prompt` dialogs.

I can also not think of a workaround, because `onbeforeupload` is an event that can't be influenced or replicated with normal JavaScript methods.

Comment: Indeed. The `beforeunload` capability is deliberately very limited, to try to prevent scripts from tricking the user.

Answer (score -2):

this line might be confusing:

```
return('Please Save Your Work Before Leaving The Page.\n\nAre You Sure?');
```

There is no such *return* function. And it should be:

```
return 'Please Save Your Work Before Leaving The Page.\n\nAre You Sure?';
```

Comment: The code was only an example and not expected to work. This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: For future reference: the parentheses are valid; it's not a function call but the return statement followed by an expression with parentheses around it. See chapter 11 and 12.9 in the specification for [ECMA-262 edition 5 (EcmaScript) specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).